# Index error in Microsoft LUIS authoring API

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding

I am using the LUIS Authoring API to send training data to a LUIS app. I am seeing a consistent index error with two virtually identical training utterances:

POST data

```
[
    {
        "text": "what are the main drivers for Aon",
        "intentName": "QI.StockOverview",
        "entityLabels": [
            {
                "entityName": "company",
                "startCharIndex": 30,
                "endCharIndex": 32
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "text": "what are the main drivers for Concho Resources",
        "intentName": "QI.StockOverview",
        "entityLabels": [
            {
                "entityName": "company",
                "startCharIndex": 30,
                "endCharIndex": 45
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I deliberately decremented `endCharIndex` by one assuming that it means "up to but not including the last character" as is common in some languages. However, I still get this response:

```
[
    {
        "value": {
            "ExampleId": 66579136,
            "UtteranceText": "what are the main drivers for aon"
        },
        "hasError": false
    },
    {
        "value": null,
        "hasError": true,
        "error": {
            "code": "FAILED",
            "message": "Example: \"what are the main drivers for Concho Resources\". Error: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.\r\nParameter name: length"
        }
    }
]
```

The message seems to be the standard C# error when one slices out a non-existent index in a string. What confuses me is that one of the utterances works and the other does not.

The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-get-started-node-add-utterance) says "Both indexes are zero-based counts", which I believe I'm doing correctly.

Any tips? Thanks

---

Edit:

I'm using the through a Python script that is mostly identical to the [this demo](https://github.com/Microsoft/LUIS-Samples/blob/master/documentation-samples/authoring-api-samples/python/add-utterances-3-6.py). I made only one change, which is to POST in batches of 90 because I have 900 training utterances and the limit per request seems to be 100. The relevant method is this:

```
def add_utterances(self, filename=UTTERANCE_FILE):
    with open(filename, encoding=self.UTF8) as utterance:
        data = json.load(utterance)

    chunk_size = 90
    print(f'Adding {len(data)} utterances in chunks of {chunk_size}')
    for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks(data, chunk_size)):
        print('chunk', i)
        self.call(self.EXAMPLES, self.POST, json.dumps(chunk))
        print(self.result)
```

The HTTP request is

`POST westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/{app_id}/versions/{app_version}/examples`

with a JSON list as the request body

Comment: Just to be sure, how are you using the API? By code, through the interface? I made a quick test with your data and don't get the error on my side

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Please see edited question

Comment: you should doublecheck your python call in order to ensure that you don't have any side effect, as from the API it's working fine

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with that code. I should point out it's pretty much identical to the demo from LUIS's github. One interesting thing I discovered is that when one utterance fails, all others in its batch fail too. I was able to submit most of my data by POST-ing in batches of 3. That way a few batches still fail, but I get 99% of my utterances sent, which is good enough for now (although it takes ages). In batches of 90 utterances I would have lost 30% of all data.